# SNS topic subscription to AmazonIpSpaceChanged using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to subscribe to the Aws AmazonIpSpaceChanged SNS topic using terraform. However, I keep getting the below error

## SNS Topic subscription to AWS

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "aws_ip_change_sns_subscription" {
  topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = "${aws_lambda_function.test_sg_lambda_function.arn}"
}
```

Error:

```
* module.test-lambda.aws_sns_topic_subscription.aws_ip_change_sns_subscription: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_sns_topic_subscription.aws_ip_change_sns_subscription: Error creating SNS topic: InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: TopicArn
        status code: 400, request id: 3daa2940-8d4b-5fd8-86e7-7b074a16ada9
```

I tried the same using aws cli and it failed the first time when I didn't include the option --region us-east-1. But once it is included, it was able to subscribe just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but there are no accepted answers - maybe this will help someone if you agree with it and mark it as accepted?

The SNS topic `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged` is only available in the region `us-east-1`, so you need to use a provider within Terraform that is configured for that region.

You also need to give permissions to the SNS topic to invoke the Lambda function (not sure if you'd just left this off the question).

This also works if your lambda function is defined in a different region.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "{your target region}"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us_east_1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_function" {

  # This uses your default target region

  :
  :
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_permission" {

  # This uses your default target region

  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSNS"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.my_function.function_name
  principal     = "sns.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "aws_ip_change_sns_subscription" {

  # This needs to use the same region as the SNS topic
  provider = aws.us_east_1

  topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = aws_lambda_function.my_function.arn
}
```

Comment: This answer actually works for me but the one from BMW above defining variable, thank you @DaveRix I would mark yours as answer if I can, but I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your topic_arn is hardcoded to region `us-east-1`:

```
arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged
```

So when you have `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` or similar configuration and point to another region, your code will fail.

That's the reason if you nominate the region, the code runs fine.

To avoid hardcodes, such as region, account id, you can do this:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

variable "region" {
  type = "string"
  default = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "aws_ip_change_sns_subscription" {
  topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:AmazonIpSpaceChanged"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = "${aws_lambda_function.test_sg_lambda_function.arn}"
}
```

With that, you should be fine and more flexible to run it in other region and other aws account as well.

Comment: You are correct. If I run the terraform code in us-east-1, it runs fine. Ideally, that should not be the case and terraform should have a way to deal with this.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer, will this make sense for you now?

Comment: Thanks @BMW. The problem is the SNS topic is the only topic available from Amazon to subscribe to the IP changes. AFAIK, there are no other topics for other regions.